# Inner Join LINQ Without making a New Model

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working with LINQ and I need to do a inner join. This is my code:

```
var requests = 
    (from request in db.Request
    join estatus in db.typesStatus
    on request.fkStatus equals estatus.idStatus
    where request.fkStatus == status && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(request.dateRquest) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
    select new { request = request, estatus = estatus.status, nombre = (String)UserAccessRequest.checkUserAsync(request.wiwMakeRequest, "name").Result })
    .ToList();
```

I'm trying to call a method inside my LINQ query. This one calls an API and returns a string but I recieved the next error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]
>   checkUserAsync(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is any way to make the LINQ query without making a model to the result of this LINQ query?

Comment: What do you mean? Nothing can make `checkUserAsync` translatable into SQL. With or without model (whatever that means), you have to work around that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your method after LINQ query loaded data into memory:

```
var requests = 
    (from request in db.Request
    join estatus in db.typesStatus
    on request.fkStatus equals estatus.idStatus
    where request.fkStatus == status && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(request.dateRquest) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fecha)
    select new { request = request, estatus = estatus.status })
    .ToList()
    .Select(i => new { i.request, i.estatus, nombre = (String)UserAccessRequest.checkUserAsync(i.request.wiwMakeRequest, "name").Result })
    .ToList()
```